# how to pivot balance amount in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

I am using this formula in I5 =G5-SUMIF($A$5:A5,A5,$K$5:K5) to calculate the outstanding amount which is getting 0 once all the fee is paid, then I am pivoting the data to compare the course Fee vs Outstanding amount as shown in the below pivot screen shot:

As per the calculation I want to compare the fee amount received vs remaining balance in the pivot of a respective reg no. If the final balance is 0 it should show in the pivot instead of adding the course outstanding entries.

Please help me out.

Sample worksheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1roEXEuBBwHU8lKV_QruY6hVjYOOkpwAwAI5x8yuYfZ8/edit#gid=339420405

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Since the balance goes down every time a payment is made every row, you can use `MIN of Course Outstanding Amount Rs` on the PivotTable values to show the final balance:

[image]